# Match two multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional array `invoice_data` and other is `post_data`. My question is I have to match `invoice_number` form `invoice_data` array in to `post_data` array. If match create `post_data` array if not match goes to else condition show `invoice_number` in to array. I tried but not working properly I think make mistake.

`invoice_data` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [invoice_no] => H146/17-18
            [invoice_date] => 2017-05-2
        )

)
```

`post_data` array

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => H146/17-18
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 71023910
            [3] => tes
            [4] => 1.01
            [5] => CTM
            [6] => 3935.19
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 00
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => H146/17-18
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 71023910
            [3] => test2
            [4] => 1.02
            [5] => CTM
            [6] => 3567.90
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 00
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => H146/17-18
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 71023910
            [3] => test3
            [4] => 1.01
            [5] => CTM
            [6] => 3462.96
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 00
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => H146/17-19
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 71023910
            [3] => test4
            [4] => 1.04
            [5] => CTM
            [6] => 2466.05
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 00
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
        )
   [3] => Array
       (
            [0] => H146/17-20
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 71023910
            [3] => test4
            [4] => 1.04
            [5] => CTM
            [6] => 2466.05
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 00
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
    )

)
```

My tried code

```
$dataSet = [];
$error_dispay = [];
$product_fob = 0;
$invoice_fob = 0;
foreach ($invoice_data as $invoicedata) {
    $invoice_fob += $invoicedata->invoice_value;
       foreach ($post_data as $postdata) {
          if (!empty($postdata)) {
              if ($invoicedata->invoice_no == $postdata[0]) {
                  $product_fob += ($postdata[6] * $postdata[4]);
                   $dataSet[] = [
                       'session_token' => $session_token,
                       'invoice_no' => $postdata[0],
                       'ritc' => $postdata[2],
                       'product_description' => $postdata[3],
                       'unit_price' => $postdata[4],
                       'quantity' => $postdata[6],
                       'amount' => ($postdata[6] * $postdata[4]),
                       'fob' => ($postdata[6] * $postdata[4]),
                       'pmv_value' => $postdata[7],
                    ];
                } else {
                    $error_dispay[] = [
                            'not_match' => $invoicedata->invoice_no
                        ];
                }
             }
           }
        }
```

If not match goes in else condition and array shows like this. See invoice number `H146/17-20` have one record but loop shows multiple time errors. How can I handle this.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-18
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-18
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-19
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-20
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-20
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-20
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [not_match] => H146/17-20
        )

)
```

Please suggest me what is my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: *invoice_value* where does it came from?

Comment: @Chinito I update my question

Comment: @rahul_m I update my question

Comment: you can have a `$ismatch = false;` before your `foreach ($post_data as $postdata) {` and set `$ismatch to true if invoice_no is found. and also you have to move your `else` for your error_display after the post_data iteration

Answer (score 0):

your first array is object so it will not going to check 3rd level value in your first foreach. You will have to use object element for that to solve this issue.
 update it with this line:

```
foreach ($invoice_data[0] as $invoicedata) {
```

This is not suggested as you are comparing object with array so you need to update your codding standard but its a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

In foreach look you dont need to pass the index.

changes the below line 
foreach ($invoice_data as $invoicedata) { with 
foreach ($invoice_data[0] as $invoicedata) { as this array is object.

if ($invoicedata->invoice_no == $postdata[0]) {
please change the above line with below code
if ($invoicedata->invoice_no == $postdata) {

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your loop arrays means `post_data` as outer loop and `invoice_data` as inner loop,

```
$dataSet      = [];
$error_dispay = [];
$product_fob  = 0;
$invoice_fob  = 0;
foreach ($post_data as $postdata) {
    foreach ($invoice_data as $invoicedata) {
        $invoice_fob += floatval($invoicedata->invoice_value);
        if (trim($invoicedata->invoice_no) == trim($postdata[0])) {
            $product_fob += floatval($postdata[6]) * floatval($postdata[4]);
            $dataSet[] = [
                'session_token'       => $session_token,
                'invoice_no'          => $postdata[0],
                'ritc'                => $postdata[2],
                'product_description' => $postdata[3],
                'unit_price'          => $postdata[4],
                'quantity'            => $postdata[6],
                'amount'              => floatval($postdata[6]) * floatval($postdata[4]),
                'fob'                 => floatval($postdata[6]) * floatval($postdata[4]),
                'pmv_value'           => $postdata[7],
            ];
        } else {
            $error_dispay['error'] = $invoicedata->invoice_no;
        }

    }
}
```

If still not working, please activate error reporting by doing

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And check what errors you are getting and debug as per that.